# How to run Scala test in Scala native application?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-native

I have hello world scala native app and wanted to run small scala test to this app I use the usual test command but it's throw an exception :

`NativeMain.scala`

```
object NativeMain {
  val p = new Person("xxxx")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello world")
  }
}
class Person(var name: String)
}
```

`NativeTest.scala`

```
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

class NativeTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "name" should "the name is set correctly in constructor" in {
    assert(NativeMain.p.name == "xxxx")
  }
}
```

I run `test` command in the `sbt` shell and got this error

```
[IJ]> test
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/****/Documents/ScalaNativeFresh/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/****/Documents/ScalaNativeFresh/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/****/Documents/ScalaNativeFresh/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[info] Linking (28516 ms)
[error] cannot link: @java.lang.Thread::getStackTrace_scala.scalanative.runtime.ObjectArray
[error] unable to link
[error] (nativetest:nativeLink) unable to link
[error] Total time: 117 s, completed Apr 2, 2019 3:04:24 PM
```

Any help or suggestions thank you :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue to add [Add support for Scala Native #111](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1112)2 and according to [cheeseng](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1112#issuecomment-366856502):

> 3.1.0-SNAP6 and 3.2.0-SNAP10 are the only 2 versions (as of the time of writing) that supports scala-native

Try importing `scalatest_native0.3_2.11` like so

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_native0.3_2.11" % "3.2.0-SNAP10"
```

[scalatest-native-example](https://github.com/mario-galic/scalatest-native-example) is a working example showing how to use scalatest with scala-native.

Comment: Thank you :) much appreciated it works ,but could I know why the test is running okay but  I got :
 0 succeeded 0 failed , No tests were executed ?